# Downloading multiple files from S3 using 'aws cli' in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to download multiple files from `S3` using `aws cli` in `python`. Using `pip install` I installed `aws cli` and was able to successfully pass credentials. But when I try to download multiple files, I get following error:
`fatal error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'us-east-1.amazonaws.com'`

My code to download the file looks like this:
`aws s3 cp "s3://buckets/testtelligence/saurav_shekhar/test/" "C:/HD/Profile data/Downloads" --recursive`

Also, my `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config` is

`[default]
region = Default region name [None]:us-east-1
output = Default output format [None]: table`

I am not sure what that error means and how to resolve this.

Comment: Does the CLI work at all? For example, can you do `aws s3 ls`? Does it work when trying to copy one file (without --recursive)?

Comment: No. It gives me the same error. Does that mean that CLI is not working? If yes then any possible resolution.

Comment: It sounds like your CLI configuration isn't correct. Please edit your question to show the contents of `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config`.  It should show `region=us-east-1` under `[default]`. See: [Configuring the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

Comment: I have edited the question and have added the content of `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config`

Comment: No, that should not be the contents. Please delete that file and run `aws configure`. It will format the file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of your `.aws/config` file should look like:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = table
```